# Monad type mismatch

Tags: haskell, monads

I am attempting to use the IO monad in a Spock application. The following code does not compile:

```
get "api/entities" $ do
  entities <- loadEntities
  let e1 : xs = entities
  text $ note e1
```

`loadEntities` has the type `IO [Entity]`

The error is `Couldn't match type ‘ActionT IO ()’ with ‘t0 -> IO b0’`

Is Spock using a monad other than IO? If so, how do I get the result of loadEntities?

Comment: Are you sure loadEntities isn't something like

`loadEntities :: a -> IO b`

You'll also probably need something like

`entities <- liftIO $ loadEntites arg`

Comment: loadEntities seems to be` IO [Entities]`, according to the compiler. liftIO worked! Is it needed because it takes place within an ActionT monad? And is the standard liftIO in the transformers library? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, the stand `liftIO` is the the transformers library under `Contol.Monad.Class.IO`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Writing answer so people can see a better explanation.

If you look at `get` it has the type.

```
get :: MonadIO m => SpockRoute -> ActionT m () -> SpockT m ()
```

`ActionT` is a monad transformer and it requires in inner monad to have an instance of `MonadIO`. If we look at the typeclass `MonadIO` it has a function

```
liftIO :: IO a -> m a
```

This means every that you call execute functions of the type `IO a` in that stack by using `liftIO`. `ActionT` has an instance of `MonadIO` also and which is the one you are using here to call your IO function. So to call `loadEntities` you had to

```
entities <- liftIO loadEntities
```

If you end of calling a certain function like that a lot you can create a separate module import it qualified and export a more friendly one.

```
module Lifted (loadEntities) where

import qualified SomeModule as IO

loadEntities :: MonadIO m => m Entities
loadEntities = liftIO IO.loadEntities
```

This will make it so you don't always have you use `liftIO`